# Measure battery consumption of an Android app

Tags: android, graph, batterylevel

I developed an Android app with auto-adaptive policy based on battery level measurement.
I'd like to measure the battery consumption and draw a graph for attaching it to my application's document. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Batterystats is not so good since I have some devices who are lower than Android 5.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.hwangti.batterylog&hl=it)

It's a nice app who actually logs data (voltage, temperature, battery status like plugged, unplugged,...) any time battery decreases and it allows to draw the graph of it.

Unluckly, it is not for the app itself but for all the system.
Enjoy.